# Identifiability of Non-Parametric Utility Function?

Tags: microeconomics, decision-theory, theory, identification

I recently learned that EU characterized by independence and weak ordering is identifiable, but a utility function like: $U(x)=v_1(x)v_2(x)$ is not identifiable.

Does it mean that "cardinal uniqueness = identifiability"? Or cardinal uniqueness implies identifiability but not the other way?

I found the precise definition of "identifiability" parametric function. But for non-parameteric function, what is the precise definition of identifiability?

For example, does the simplest utility function $u(x)$ characterized by weak order and continuity identifiable by its own? (a.k.a does ordinal uniqueness implies identifiability?)

Comment: So what is the definition of identifiability for parametric functions and in what sense is EU parametric?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker EU is non-parametric in this case.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker For parametric functions, identifiable means that any two different parameter vectors cannot give the same value.

Comment: Non-parametric does not mean there are no parameters, it usually means the parameter space is infinite-dimensional (which would also be the case with EU with infinitely many outcomes). So the same definition works in a non-parametric setting.